# Reading from CGI.PM file by chunks

Tags: apache, perl, cgi.pm

We have a file, sent from HTML form to CGI (perl) script.
We know, that files came from HTML via CGI.PM are paged onto disk (as an alternative for RAM). And in this case I have a question: is it possible to read a file by chunks from that memory into CGI script (say, into array)?
The code we have as simple as possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );

my $q = new CGI;

my @file = $q->upload("file"); # here I think must be some while(<>) {} for reading from N byte to X byte.
```

And if it is possible then I have a second sub-question: is it possible to read different chunks (say: fro the beginning from 0 to 500 bytes, then from 1000 to 1500, then from 501 to 999 bytes? Thanks!

Comment: When I see "CGI.PM", I find myself wondering if you are using VMS or DOS.

Comment: @tjd When I see your comment I find myself wondering what is VMS and DOS (unless you mean DOS as OS)? Wdn't you, please, kindly explain? Thanks!

Comment: VMS & DOS are two OSs that use strictly upper case file names.  In most any other OS the file name would be "CGI.pm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html).

Comment: Thanks! ikegami, as always)) Great stuff!